# Prove HEP with Yoneda

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

If there is given an top. embedding $i:A \subset X$ and there exists a retraction $r: X\times I \to A\times I \cup X\times \{0\}$ I want to show that this induces the cofibration property of $i$, therefore HEP holds:

For given $g:X \to Y$ and homotopy $h:A \times I \to Y$ with $g \circ i = h(-,0)|_A$ and $h(-,0) = g$ there exist a homotopy $H: X \times I \to Y$ such that $H|_{i(A) \times I}=h$.

The crux of the matter is that I found already some proofs in Hatcher and TvDieck but I heard that there is an elegant way to prove using Yoneda lemma. Unfortunately I don't see how ...

Comment: Try to follow the guided exercise of J. Strom, *Modern Classical Homotopy Theory* claimed in Prop. 5.8. It is not properly the Yoneda lemma you're using there, but the proof is quite abstract :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$There is indeed a formal proof of this result, but apart the fact that it is based on the universal property of pushouts it seems a bit of a stretch to claim that you're using Yoneda lemma.

[image]

in this diagram the universal property of $T = (A\times I) \cup_A X$ gives an arrow $T\to Y$; the existence of a retraction for the other canonical map $T \to X\times I$ amounts precisely to the request that $i$ has the HEP.

For the sake of completeness, I remember that the following conditions are equivalent (all come from Strom book):

1. $i : A \subset X$ has the HEP
2. $id_T$ can be extended to an homotopy $X\times I\to T$
3. $T \hookrightarrow X\times I$ has a retraction $r : X\times I \to T$
4. $T \hookrightarrow X\times I$ is a strong deformation retract of $X\times I$.

Most (but not all) of these equivalences are proven invoking the universal property of $T$, as above.

Comment: There is one detail with isn't clear to me. Why do you can identify $A \times I \cup X \times 0$ with the pushout $T = (A\times I) \dot\cup_A X \times 0$ with respect to their topologies? That's certainly clear considering them as sets. Futhermore the canonical map  $m: (A\times I) \dot\cup X \times 0 \to A \times I \cup X \times 0 $ factorises over $T$ with $  m = pr \circ t $, where $pr$ is the canonical projection from $(A\times I) \dot\cup X \times 0$ to $T$ and $t$ the bijection $T \to A \times I \cup X \times 0 $ for which we have to prove the continuity.

Comment: According the univ property of disjuct sum $m$ is continuous, so $t$ also according to quotient topology property. My problem staying unclear to identify $T$ with $A \times I \cup X$ is to show that $t^{-1}$ is continuous too... 
Do you see an argument?

Comment: It's a standard and quite boring trick in general topology: the pushout can be obtained as quotient of a disjoint union, so that it has a well-defined (and universal) disjoint union topology and quotient topology. The relevant maps are continuous wrt these topologies

Comment: I think it's not quite that simple. See prop A.18 in Hatcher: https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATapp.pdf

Comment: My religion prevents me from considering the whole category of topological space and only gives me convenient ones :-)

Comment: A reasonable religion!